# Invoke-WmiMethod - Quickly fix PsRemoting/WinRM problems (for Invoke-Command usage)

Tags: powershell, wmi

In the event you have computers that are unreachable with Invoke-Command either because WinRm is not running or PsRemoting is disabled here is a good, sure way I've found works everytime, in my environement at least:

```
 $target_comp = "abc1234"

 Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $target_comp -Path win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe -command Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force"
 Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $target_comp -Path win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe -command winrm quickconfig -quiet"


 do {
     $testpsremoting = invoke-command -computername $target_comp -scriptblock {"test"}
    } while (!$testpsremoting) 



    #REST OF CODE
```

Explanation :

-Declare variable of your computer name.
-Run the two commands to enable PsRemoting and setup WinRM via Invoke-WmiMethod.
***Since Invoke-WmiMethod returns instantly without WAITING for the commands to actually be done:** 

-Make a loop that runs until PsRemoting is enabled (until the test Invoke-Command works).

No more Invoke-Command problems! Enjoy and fine tune to your heart's content.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to get back from this call?  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx) states that the `Create()` method only returns the `ProcessID` of the launched process, so it looks to me like it is working as expected.

Comment: Yeah , it seems i'm not using the right command. In fact i wanted to run my commands with Invoke-WmiMethod to prevent having to do Invoke-Command. Now I realized i just have to enable PSRemoting with Invoke-WmiMethod and THEN use Invoke-Command freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question changed to provide answer and useful fix for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Get-wmi to get the result directly

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_service -ComputerName $poste | select State,Name,DisplayName
```

Comment: Thanks but the get-service was an example in this case. I ended up using Invoke-WmiMethod to enable PSRemoting then use Invoke Command freely.